# Get a number from a site with curl and then using it in my application

Tags: php, curl

I am messing with curl to extract a number from a site, and I got that working nice an dandy.

The problem is the variable I get is an object type and hence I cannot interact with the variable on my site as I would like, and I have Googled a lot and what I found is that you cannot convert an object to a float.

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$url = "https://oilprice.com/oil-price-charts";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);

foreach($html->find('tr[data-id="46"]') as $link);
foreach($link->find('td[3]') as $link);

echo $link . "<br>";
```

Comment: Not sure why your looping, you only have one matching element so `echo $html->find('tr[data-id="46"] td[3]', 0)->plaintext` would probably do the trick.

Comment: You should prob read section 10(b) https://oilprice.com/terms-and-conditions also.. ;p

Comment: Yeah that is true, that way is better, still dosnt fix my problem, if i do like this and assign the findings to a variable it is of the type object and cannot be used for calculations, if i force the variable to double it only returns 1.

Comment: Indeed i should have, will use another site that allows this, if i can get my problem fixed, actually thinking echoing it out in json format and then get it with an ajax call might work...

Comment: That did the trick, thx for the reply tough.